# Probably a simple jest/react error on my part

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I am trying to mock a component that has the following structure:

```
//A_Form.js
import React from "react";

export default React.createClass({
    displayname: "A_Form",

    updateState: function() {
        // I want to mock this function as it opens a web connection
    }    
    render: function() {
        return ( 
            <form>
                <div className='class1'>
                    <label htmlFor="name"> name </label>
                </div>
            </form>
    }
```

I'm trying to test this with jest using the following:

```
//A_Form.spec.js
import React
import {A_Form} from './A_Form';

function mock_A_Form() {
    var A_Form = React.createElement(require.requireActual("./A_Form");
    return {
        ... A_Form,
        updateState: jest.fn( () => { return; } )
    }
jest.mock("./A_Form",() => { return mock_A_Form(); } );

describe("A_Form test",function() {
    var ReactTestUtils = require('react-addons-test-utils');
    var a_form = React.createElement(require.requireMock("./A_Form");

    it("checking",function() {
        var n = "name";
        var rendered_a_form = ReactTestUtils.renderIntoDocument(a_form);
        var my_name = ReactTestUtils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithTag(rendered_a_form,"label");
        expect(my_name.textContent).toBe(n);
    });
});
```

I think I have included all of the relevant code.  I am stuck with I call renderIntoDocument as it returns "Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.".

As I am rather new to Jest and React any push in reasonable direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Ah ok, I think I see what's going on:

```
var a_form = React.createElement(require.requireMock("./A_Form");
```

looks to be the line that's throwing the error. `require.requireMock("./A_Form")` produces an object (`React.createElement` requires a component or string):

```
{
    ... A_Form,
    updateState: jest.fn( () => { return; } )
}
```

If I understand correctly, you want to return a Component, with the `updateState` method overwritten. However, what you've ended up doing is producing an object with all the methods and fields of `A_Form` (if that, I don't think you can unpack an object like that - for me, at least, Babel complains about that unpacking) and an `updateState` method.

Unfortunately, there's not really a good, easy way to just do method overrides in React - take a look at [this post](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/mixins-are-dead-long-live-higher-order-components-94a0d2f9e750), I think it'll point you in the right direction. At a high level, instead of overriding, you'll just be supplying methods to be overriden to the component when you create them.

There are also [libraries](https://discuss.reactjs.org/t/best-practices-for-extending-subclassing-components/1820/4) for "true" OO in React... although it seems kind of excessive.

You can *try* something like

```
return React.createComponent({ ...A_Form, updateState: () => {});
```

not sure if it'll work, though.